# Access the textbox value from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic gridview ...and it has four columns..what I want is to access the textbox value in the gridview from the last column "amount paid" and display its total sum value in a label.Below is the code that I have tried. can someone let me know how to do this?

ASP.NET

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview2" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" CssClass="vutblrow" 
                                                                TabIndex="3" HeaderStyle-CssClass="vutblhdr"
                                                                CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  Width="1%"  
                                                                PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" 


            AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowcreated="Gridview2_RowCreated" Height="16px">
              <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"  Height="25px" BorderStyle="Solid" />
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Serial Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From Place">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textfrom" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To Place">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Textto" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Distance Travelled (kms)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxdist" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>




           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount Paid (per km)">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxamt" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxNormalmedium"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd1" runat="server" Text="Add New Row"
                         CssClass="btnNormalAdd" OnClick="add" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
                        CssClass="lnkbut" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Remove</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>


                                                         <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

C# code:

```
namespace Test.Test
{
   public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (!IsPostBack)
         {
            SetInitialRow1();
         }
      }

      private void AddNewRowToGrid1()
      {
         int rowIndex = 0;

         if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
         {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
               {
                  //extract the TextBox values
                  TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Textfrom");
                  TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("Textto");
                  TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBoxdist");
                  TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBoxamt");

                  drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                  drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                  dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                  dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                  dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box3.Text;
                  dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column4"] = box4.Text;

                  rowIndex++;
               }
                  dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                  ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;
                  Gridview2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                  Gridview2.DataBind();
           }
        }
        else
        {
           Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData1();
   }

   private void SetPreviousData1()
   {
      int rowIndex = 0;
      if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
      {
         DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
               TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Textfrom");
               TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("Textto");
               TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBoxdist");
               TextBox box4 = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBoxamt");

               box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
               box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
               box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
               box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();

               rowIndex++;
             }
          }
      }
   }

   protected void add(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      AddNewRowToGrid1();
   }

   protected void Gridview2_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
         DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
         LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
         if (lb != null)
         {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
               if (e.Row.RowIndex == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
               {
                  lb.Visible = false;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               lb.Visible = false;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
      GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
      int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex + 1;
      if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
      {
         DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
         {
            if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
               //Remove the Selected Row data
               dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);
            }
         }
         //Store the current data in ViewState for future reference
         ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
         //Re bind the GridView for the updated data
         Gridview2.DataSource = dt;
         Gridview2.DataBind();
      }
      //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
     SetPreviousData1();
   }  

   private void SetInitialRow1()
   {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      DataRow dr = null;
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));

      dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
      dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
      dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
      dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
      dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;

      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      //dr = dt.NewRow();

      //Store the DataTable in ViewState
      ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

      Gridview2.DataSource = dt;
      Gridview2.DataBind();
   }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your label is defined after/below your GridView. Are you trying to total all of the values, or just display the total amount for each row?

Comment: Hi,specify you problem clearly.there is no column named total amount in the gridview.If you want to show total of column values from gridview. or just want to access the textbox in any event.

Comment: yes i want to display the total of all the values from the amount paid..column

Comment: Why is your amount paid textbox duplicated?

Comment: I am sorry that was by mistake...i have edited the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
 TextBox TextBox1 = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox; 

  //Access TextBox1 here.
  string myString = TextBox1.Text;
```

Text box is the child control inside in gridview row so you can iterate above code for each grid view row.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please isolate the data source?

This will clarify your mind and the question. As soon you have a Service/Repository to query the data source you can take advantage of linq and do something simple like:

```
var sum = datasource.Sum(p=>p.AmountPaid);
```