# Change textbox value placed inside gridview in c# windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to change the textbox placed inside a gridview value, if the value is not numeric I want textbox to place 0 at that column position

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // column to check for only numeric values
    {
        int i;

        if (!int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue), out i))
        {
            e.Cancel = true; // halting the tool till correct value in the cell but I want that instead of this line I want to place a value in that cell

        }
        else
        {
           // the input is numeric 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use the FindControl() method.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666785/access-the-textbox-value-from-gridview

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = 0;`

Comment: I added my answer below, If you found any difficulties to implement then let me know :)